# How to set response headers in JAX-RS resource

Tags: jax-rs, response-headers

In a typical java servlet ie:

```
public class SomeClass extends HttpServlet
```

There are doGet and doPost methods that have the `HttpServletRequest request` and `HttpServletResponse response` objects as arguments that allows me to set the response headers as such:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // or other domain
```

I'm working on a java web app where the classes aren't servlets but are JAX-RS resources such as:

```
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String getData(@QueryParam("Data1") String data1, @QueryParam("Data2") String data2 {
// do some code
}
```

How do I set the response headers in such case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Context to acquire the headers object.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getExample(@Context HttpHeaders headers) {
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    return "{\"message\":\"Hello, World!\"}";
}
```